# How does the Newton's constant get renormalized in Quantum Gravity with matter?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, renormalization, quantum-gravity, physical-constants

In quantum gravity with matter, say e.g. $R$ + $\partial\phi_{\mu} \partial\phi^{\mu}$, even the one loop correction is non-renormalizable. I am sure many smart people have already worked on this, so I would like some references which contain classifications of these divergences. I am interested in the (divergent) term which renormalizes $G_N$ at 1-loop. The diagram I am referring to, is the graviton propagator, with $\phi$ running in the loop. A full answer discussing these divergences is also welcome. Thanks in advance.